# Add input fields based on condition with Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

In Gravity Forms, I have a form containing some input fields asking for number of rooms for each room type.

How can I dynamically add input fields for number of each content in the room? Eg if the previous input field was entered as 
Bedrooms: 2

Then how can I dynamically add a section or table asking for quantity of contents for each room such as:

**Bedroom 1**

Bed (Kind): n

Bed (Queen): n

Content N: n...

**Bedroom 2**

Bed (Kind): n

Bed (Queen): n

Content N: n...

Is there a advanced field to do this?  I guess I may need to use JS to do this? 
If so, how can I make sure these fields can be seen in entries?

I'm thinking of using table, but not sure how to with Gravity Forms.

Comment: Not sure about this, but have you considered using conditional logic?  If I recall correctly, it is an inbuilt feature but effectively it would work something like "only show bedroom 1 section if no_of_room is equal to or is more than 1" and then "only show bedroom 2 section if no_of_room equals to or is more than 2"

Was initially thinking about the Dynamic population feature but not sure it would really apply in this case.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought of too. But if I have a max of 10 room numbers allowed then I would need to setup 10 or so conditional logic and input fields, right?!

Comment: How would one show sections? Like you mentioned Bedroom N section which wraps input fields for the number of contents in a room...is it possible to group these into section in Gravity Form? If so how?

Comment: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Section_Break  I can't say if having multiple sections is the best way forward though.  One other option might be to create these repeating list fields: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/List (and change them to other types using e.g. http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_column_input)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet out of the box is using the [List field](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/List). You can enable multiple columns for each bedroom feature (i.e. "Bed (King)", "Bed (Queen)", "Content", etc) and then each bedroom would be represented by a row on the list field. The user can add/remove bedrooms via a plus/minus UI at the end of each row.

Alternately, if you will have a large number of fields per row, I have a perk in the works called "GP Nested Forms". It's a little easier to show how it works than explain (see the video below) but the primary purpose is a clean way to include decent sized forms within other forms, especially when you need to add multiple instances of the child form.

http://www.screencast.com/t/p7sAHutMVfG

If this interests you, you can pick up a copy of [Gravity Perks here](http://gravitywiz.com/gravity-perks) and I can send you a copy of the Nested Forms perk (not yet publicly available).

**Edit**

This has been further polished here:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/

Comment: Ah ok, the idea in the 1st paragraph is good. But I may have 10 or more contents/features listed for each type of room. Is it possible to layout the table such as this: http://tinypic.com/r/2zfmlj7/8

Comment: So laying out the columns in 1 row wouldn't be ideal...I like this implementation though: http://gravitywiz.com/require-all-columns-of-list-field/   Not sure how I would do this with many features/contents fields for each room

Comment: For the child form, would you be able to provide the perk you are mentioning voluntarily? Or do I have to purchase the entire copy of package? I just require this one functionality..

Comment: I will use list field instead as you suggested. I would like to know following to customize list field:
How can I change the input type of the fields in the list to number instead of text type?
Add text at the start of each row so that I get Room 1, Room 2, etc for each row....once row(s) are added?
Space the columns out evenly rather than dependent on the text for each column heading?